# What does the term 'equivalent' mean in C++ standard?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

According to the [draft of the C++ 11 standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf), page 421, Table 23 — CopyAssignable, it says that post-condition of an expression `t = v` of copyassignable type is

> t is equivalent to v, the value of v is unchanged

But I'm not sure what the term 'equivalent' means here. Is it mean `t == v`? Or something like all bytes are equivalent 'deeply' in sense of 'deepcopy'?

Comment: Sounds like a "soft" requirement to me (without a strict definition). Since CopyAssignable types don't have to implement `==`, I doubt it means `==`.

Comment: Is that mean everyone understands as my second understanding(deeply equivalent)?

Comment: "Deeply equivalent" is vague, especially when applied to individual bytes rather than the whole object. Yes, I guess.

Comment: On https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_assignable this requirement of `CopyAssignable` is called a semantic requirement. So not deepcopy-equivalent, but depending on the classes, not decidable by a machine/algorithm, but by human interpretation.

Comment: English language definitions of "equivalent" are something like "equal in by some measure" or "equal in value, measure, impact, force, effect or significance".  If `t` and `v` can be compared using `t == v`, then `t` and `v` might be deemed equivalent if `t == v` gave a `true` (or non-zero if it is not a `bool`) result. If they can't be compared using `t == v` then there would be some other expression that, if it gives a chosen result, indicates equivalence - for example, if `t != v` is a valid expression, then equivalence of `t` and `v` may be deemed as "`t != v` gives a `false` result".

Comment: @Peter I think I don't understand. Do you mean that I can even say `t` and `v` are equivalent because their types are equal?

Comment: One more question: So every class `T` that have assignment operator defined as return type of `T&` and return value of `this` meets the copyassignable requirement, regardless of what they actually do?

Comment: It could be context dependent. Like [filesystem::equivalent](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/equivalent) means that two filenames refer to the same file (can be symlinks), while operator== means that the *names* themselves compare equal

Comment: @kjh6b6a68  No I don't mean that `t` and `v` are equivalent because they have the same type.  An `int` with value `2` and an `int` with value `4` are often not considered to be equivalent (nor are they considered equal), despite having the same type.   But, *for the purpose of some program*, those two values might be deemed equivalent (say, if they result in the same action by your program).

Comment: @kjh6b6a68   There's more to CopyAssignable than you describe.  CopyAssignable also includes a requirement of MoveAssignable.    Additionally, the expression `t = v` (where `v` is either an lvalue expression or an rvalue expression of `const` type) must have the effect of ensuring `t` is equivalent to `v` (by whatever manner is defined for your program), must not change `v`.     If *you* specify (for purposes of your program or library) that `t == v` means that `t` and `v` are equivalent, but `t == v` is not a post-condition of your assignment operator, then the type is not CopyAssignable

Comment: _But I'm not sure what the term 'equivalent' means here._ I think the idea is that `t` can be passed to a function `f` and it won't be able to distinguish it from `v`, if `f` has some properties, e.g. it shall not care about addresses.

Comment: They mean equal except equal would be taken as `operator==` and that might not exist. Maybe this helps: Given `T a, b, c;` it is impossible to determine which of the following was performed by just inspecting `c`: `c = a;` or `b = a; c = b;`.

Comment: @Peter Now I think I understand, but one more question. Do you think 'value of v is unchanged' must be interpreted similarly? Does the meaning of the word 'unchanged' also depends on how I define it?

Comment: @kjh6b6a68   It means that any code using `v` cannot detect a change of `v`.

Comment: We are talking about `value types`. Certain operations do not count, when determining equivalency, foremost taking the address or reading the internal data. You may use the (public) interface.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no separate definition of the term "equivalent" that would apply in the standard. It may be interpreted as plain English. Here are a few definitions from dictionaries:

> - corresponding or virtually identical especially in effect or function
> - equal to or having the same effect as something
> - something that is the same amount, price, size, etc. as something else or has the same purpose as something else

---

Another interpretation is that your quote is the definition for equivalent in this context i.e. the meaning of equality for the type in question is defined by the assignment operator of that type.